# I can not get the $route.params

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

In the Page1 I pass the query to Page2:

```
this.$router.push({name: 'physicalserver_task_one_key', query: {task_id: params.row.id}})
```

and I debugger there, the `params.row.id` is 25.

in the Page2, I can see the url of browser:

```
localhost:8080/physicalserver_task_one_key_put_in_storage?task_id=25
```

but in the Page2, I can not get the `task_id` by:

```
this.$route.params.task_id
```

I also debugger the `this.$route.params`, which result is `{}`.

Comment: query and params are different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `this.$route.query.task_id to` receive query params。
see https://router.vuejs.org/api/#route-object-properties